# Hibernate auto_increment MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, xampp

I am using Eclipse, Xammp (tomcat and MySQL DB) and Hibernate.

this all works good, but I can't create that the ID from the Entity will be `auto_increment` in the Database

My Entity:

```
package com.jwt.hibernate.bean;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;



@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    private Long userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password1;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String city;


    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword1() {
        return password1;
    }

    public void setPassword1(String password1) {
        this.password1 = password1;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

I create a hbm.xml for this Entity with a Plugin from Hibernate and use `Hibernate XML Mapping file(hbm.xml)`:
Created hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 06.05.2016 11:59:26 by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.jwt.hibernate.bean.User" table="USER">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="USERID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="userName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="USERNAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="password1" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PASSWORD1" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EMAIL" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PHONE" />
        </property>
        <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CITY" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="/com/jwt/hibernate/bean/User.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

If i start my Code, the Console do:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER
Hibernate: create table USER (USERID bigint not null, USERNAME varchar(255), PASSWORD1 varchar(255), EMAIL varchar(255), PHONE varchar(255), CITY varchar(255), primary key (USERID))
```

Every thing  is fine but my ID isn't `auto_increment` and I don't know why.
I tried a lot of Annotations.
other Annotations for Example `ManyToMany` or `ManyToOne` works, but nut the `@GeneratedValue`

Comment: Don't use annotations and `hbm.xml` mapping both for the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
    <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="USERID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
```

Instead of following line

```
    <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="USERID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
```

Comment: This works.

THANK YOU SO MUCH.

i don't now why Hibernate Plugin creating a wrong hbm.xml

but now
`Hibernate: create table USER (USERID bigint not null auto_increment, USERNAME varchar(255), PASSWORD1 varchar(255), EMAIL varchar(255), PHONE varchar(255), CITY varchar(255), primary key (USERID))`

Comment: i did, i had to wait 5 minits after my Questien to Aceept this.

Do you now why eclips is generating it like
`    <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="USERID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>`

and not like
`<generator class="assigned" />`
?

Comment: @NiklasEhrenholz Probably, it is for an old Hibernate version

Answer (score 1):

You can do use this annotations on your getUserId method :

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getUserId() {
      return userId;
}
```

or you can also do this in your current code just specify @Column on getUserId method

```
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getUserId() {
      return userId;
}
```

Comment: you mean `@Entity
public class User {
 
    private Long userId;`

and before the setter 
`@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getUserId() {
      return userId;
}`

so thet the Antotations jus before the setter and not before the `private Long userId`

Comment: yes you should specify the above Annotations on the getter method for id

Comment: Please, don't use unnecessary annotations like `@Column(unique = true)` for the primary key columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use annotations, this is pretty enough

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getUserId() {
      return userId;
}
```